# Wpf drag operation to Windows Explorer doesnt work

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, com, drag

I wrote this code to perform a shell style file drag operation from my wpf application to windows explorer:

```
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject src = (DependencyObject)(e.OriginalSource);
    while (!(src is Control))
    {
        src = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(src);
    }
    string clicked_element_name = src.GetType().Name;

    if (clicked_element_name != "ListViewItem")
    {
        this.ExListView.UnselectAll();
        this.ExListView.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        
        ListViewItem item = src as ListViewItem;
        FileExplorerItem explorerItem = item.Content as FileExplorerItem;
        CDataObject dataObject = new CDataObject();

        if (dataObject != null)
        {
            List<string> filePaths = GetSelectedListViewItemsPaths();
            String fileList = "";
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                fileList += filePath + char.MinValue;
                
            }
            fileList += char.MinValue;

            // Allocate memory for the DROPFILES structure
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DROPFILES)) + (fileList.Length + 2) *2; // Length of the string plus one for the double null terminator
            IntPtr hGlobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

            // Initialize the DROPFILES structure
            DROPFILES dropFiles = new DROPFILES();
            unsafe
            {
                dropFiles.pFiles = sizeof(DROPFILES); // Offset to the file list
            }
            dropFiles.fWide = true; // Indicates that the file list is in Unicode format
            byte[] dropFilesBuffer = new byte[size];
            IntPtr dropFilesPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(dropFiles));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(dropFiles, dropFilesPtr, true);
            Marshal.Copy(dropFilesPtr, dropFilesBuffer, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(dropFiles));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dropFilesPtr);

            // Copy the file list to the global memory
            byte[] fileListBuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(fileList.ToString());
            Marshal.Copy(fileListBuffer, 0, hGlobal + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DROPFILES)), fileListBuffer.Length);

            // Copy the DROPFILES structure to the global memory
            Marshal.Copy(dropFilesBuffer, 0, hGlobal, dropFilesBuffer.Length);

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FORMATETC formatec = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FORMATETC();
            formatec.dwAspect = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT;
            formatec.lindex = -1;
            formatec.tymed = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL;
            formatec.cfFormat = (short)DataFormats.GetDataFormat(DataFormats.FileDrop).Id;

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STGMEDIUM stgmedium = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STGMEDIUM();
            stgmedium.tymed = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL;
            stgmedium.unionmember = hGlobal;

            IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
            
            dataObject.SetData(ref formatec, ref stgmedium, true);
            
            try
            {
                int hr = DragHelper.SHDoDragDrop(hwnd, dataObject, null, DragDropEffects.Copy, out var result);
                if (hr < 0)
                {
                    throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle the case when dataObject is null
        }
    }
}
```

A successfull drop is performed on Windows Exlporer, hResult returns 262400, but nothing happens the file doesnt get copied, it is as no file drop ever happend.
My guess is that there is something wrong with the way i provide the filepaths to the DROPFILES Struct, but i cant figure it out.

I tried differnt ways of providing the filepaths to the struct but nothing helps.
Maybe somebody can lead me on the right path?

Comment: You use lots of interop for which we don't have the code, so it's difficult to say w/o a full reproducing project https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: youre right, i will provide a reproducible example as soon as possible.